# How can I access a virtual machine running on a remote machine directly?

Tags: routing, nat

- My local Lubuntu's wifi IP address is 192.168.1.97
- A remote Lubuntu's wifi IP address is 192.168.1.198,
- A virtual machine running on the remote Lubuntu has IP address  192.168.122.169.

I can access the virtual machine from my local machine, indirectly by ssh to the remote by `ssh t@192.168.1.198`, and then ssh to the virtual machine by `ssh t@192.168.122.169`.

I can access the local machine from the virtual machine, directly by `ssh t@192.168.1.97`.

Because of the routing table on my local Lubuntu, I can't access the virtual machine directly from my local machine

```
$ ssh t@192.168.122.169
ssh: connect to host 192.168.122.169 port 22: No route to host
```

Can I access the virtual machine directly from my local Lubuntu?

- Do I have to modify the routing tables of my local Lubuntu and the remote Lubuntu?
- Can NAT help?

Thanks.

The routing table on the local Lubuntu is

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlx801f02b5c389
172.17.0.0      0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 docker0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlx801f02b5c389
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

The routing table on the remote Lubuntu is

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.1.1     0.0.0.0         UG    600    0        0 wlp5s0
192.168.1.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     600    0        0 wlp5s0
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 virbr0
```

The routing table on the virtual machine is:

```
$ route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.122.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 ens3
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1000   0        0 ens3
192.168.122.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 ens3
```

Comment: IMHO this is a question about networking rather than about Unix or Linux. You either *bridge* the network interface on the VM (so it shares the same address range as the host) or forward across the NAT. See for example [Introduction to Networking Modes](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch06.html#networkingmodes) in particular the "VM←Net/LAN" column of Table 6.1

Comment: I am using kvm.

Comment: AFAIK the principle is the same regardless of the particular VM platform - if you believe that is not the case, please [edit] your question to make that clear.

Answer (score 3):

Use `ProxyJump` or `ProxyCommand`.

Add this to your `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host vmhost
    User t
    Hostname 192.168.1.198

Host vm
    Hostname 192.168.122.169
    User t
    ProxyJump vmhost
```

or for older versions of `ssh` instead `ProxyJump vmhost`:

```
ProxyCommand ssh -q -W 192.168.122.169:22 vmhost
```

Connect using:

```
ssh vm
```

Comment: Thanks. Is there a solution which is no ssh specific?

Comment: This should work for `scp` and `ssh`. But for general routing, you somehow need to setup a proxy on the vm host.

Comment: Thanks. How do you setup a proxy on the vm host?

Comment: Sorry, don't know how to do it. Maybe network bridge is enough. Might be worth a second question.

Comment: Is the way in your reply called SSH local port forwarding, or something else?

Comment: No, that is something different.

Comment: Is  the way in your reply called agent forwarding, or something else?

Comment: Also is `ssh -J user@vmhost user@vmguest`  the same as those commands in your reply?

Comment: Yes it is the same, but only available with newer versions of `ssh`, it's called Proxyjump or using a jump/intermediate Host. You can also chain mutiple hosts. See: https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/OpenSSH/Cookbook/Proxies_and_Jump_Hosts

Comment: Thanks. Is proxy jump a proxy or port forwarding or something  else?