# Which concept does ssh "proxy jump" belong to: proxy, port forwarding or something else?

Tags: ssh, proxy, port-forwarding

Which concept does ssh "proxy jump" belong to: proxy, port forwarding or something else?

By  [ssh "proxy jump"](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/509195/how-can-i-access-a-virtual-machine-running-on-a-remote-machine-directly#comment941009_509204), I mean either

```
ssh -J user@vmhost user@vmguest
```

or in `~/.ssh/config`:

```
Host vmhost
    User t
    Hostname 192.168.1.198

Host vm
    Hostname 192.168.122.169
    User t
    ProxyJump vmhost
```

and they are the same (if I am correct).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It is definitely *not* port forwarding, because there are specific flags for those options. Look at the `-D` and `-L` options in the man for an explanation and specific details.

I believe the answer is **something else**.

Also from the man:

> If **command** is specified, it is executed on the remote host instead of a login shell.

So to break down your first example:

```
     ssh -J user@vmhost user@vmguest
            ^^              ^^
       (user@)hostname   [command to execute]
```

Basically and in plain English you are executing SSH locally, indicating you want to connect to **vmhost** as *user*, and that you want to execute the command `ssh user@vmguest` after you have connected.